# Image being assigned to PictureBox control by WinForms designer is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox, windows-forms-designer

I've added a picture to the PictureBox control, but the `designer.cs` file is trying to assign the image as a type instead of an actual picture:

```
this.BTNPCTAttributeList.Image = typeof(DI.Properties.Resources).Attributes;
```

I can change this and it will run fine, but the file is automatically rewritten by the designer. How can I stop this from happening?

I tried resetting the picture to blank and re-adding a new picture box, yet still it continues.

Comment: How is `this.BTNPCTAttributeList.Image` defined?

Comment: It is set through the properties panel in the VS designer as it's a static control on the form. One other picturebox did it for me but resetting it to no image and then changing it back fixed that.

Comment: Not enough information.  Let's see the rest of the declarations in that designer.cs file.  Did you use the property page image picker?  And did you select "Local resource" or "Project resource file"?  Did you import or add it by hand?  etc...